# Is the set of products $a \cdot b$ open or compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm working on a textbook problem:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets of numbers. Define the set $A\cdot B$ to be the sets of all products $a \cdot b$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.
>
> $(a).$ If $A$ is open, is $A \cdot B$ open?

I tried using $(0,1) \cdot \mathbb{Z}$ as a counterexample but I think it might be open as well, since it seems that $(0,1) \subseteq (0,1) \cdot \mathbb{Z}$. I think that $A \cdot B$ is open if $A \subseteq A \cdot B$ or if $B$ has an identity element of $A$. Then if every point of $A$ has a neighborhood in $A$, those same points will have neighborhoods in $A \cdot B$

> $(b).$ If $A$ and $B$ are compact, is the set $A \cdot B$ also compact?

Using the property that $A$ and $B$ are both closed and bounded, surely $A \cdot B$ would be closed and bounded as well? Not really sure how I would prove this. If neither of these are true, could we tweak them a little to be true?

Any pointers in the right direction appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(a) Not in general: of course, $A\cdot\{0\}=\{0\}$, which is not open. However, there are two special cases worth mentioning. If $\alpha\ne 0$ and $A$ is open, then $\alpha A$ is open. Using the fact that $A\cdot B=\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}bA$, you get that, if $0\notin B$, then $A\cdot B$ is open. With the same idea, you can show that, if $A$ is open and $0\in A$, then $A\cdot B$ is open whenever $B\ne\{0\}$.

(b) The set $A\cdot B$ is the image of $A\times B\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ through the continuous map $(x,y)\mapsto xy$.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. For part $(b)$, If I understand you correctly, the continuous map that you have given is a homeomorphism, so it preserves the compactness property?

Comment: @GeorgeDilla No, it's not a homeomorphism, because it is neither injective nor closed - the image of $\Bbb Z\times (\{0\}\cup\{1/n\,:\,n\in\Bbb Z^*\})$ is $\Bbb Q$. It is true, in general, that the image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact.